# Time Machine starts backup but stop and never starts again

Tags: backup, time-machine

I had Time Machine configured and working, then one day it stopped working and got stuck on preparing backup. I ended up wiping the backup drive and had Time Machine start new. It finds the drive and begins to back up but then it never finishes, in fact it will start every hour but never finish.

I have exhausted everything on Google that I could find. Is there a way to wipe the Time Machine config files and start fresh on Mac OS?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. I'm aware it's been around for quite a while, since Sierra, and don't think it's been fixed as yet.

Try [The Time Machine Mechanic (T2M2)](https://eclecticlight.co/downloads/) which should give more information about the error. It also includes a help file with advice and resolutions.

Comment: The logs tell me that "The file “Backups.backupdb” doesn’t exist.". I wiped the computer last night and started fresh. It was working when I went to bed last night and now it isn't.

Comment: @BrandonWilson what do the logs say now? Regardless, I have a feeling your external drive is faulty.

Comment: That is the logs from today. The odd thing is, my wifes MB Pro backs up just fine. I did notices that the backup drive was not mounted earlier, which possibly why it didn't exist.

Comment: What is the external drive and how are you connecting it to each computer? Please update your question and provide as much detail as possible.